# Cannot link gfortran and R on Mac mountain lion when creating shared objects?

Tags: r, package, fortran

I am using MAC OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.5 with Xcode 5.1. I have installed command line tools in Xcode. I tried the gfortran-4.2 found [here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/). It worked OK on my Mac if I ran complete fortran programs, but whenever I tried to use "R CMD SHLIB" for a subroutine or use "R CMD INSTALL" to install packages including fortran source codes, problems occurred during the dynamic linking stage. Now I am using gfortran-4.8 instead of gfortran-4.2, but by default R wants to use gfortran-4.2 and it seems to look for some specific fortran libraries that do not lie in the correct place on my computer. I am wondering if there is any way to create a Makevars file that give the correct F77, FFLAGS, FLIBS, FC, FCFLAGS, and FCLIBS values specific to my computer. If this is possible, how should I do it? Thanks very much!

Comment: Which libraries are "some specific"?

Comment: Solved the problem by downgrading Xcode to 4.5. Thanks anyway!